# Regex for date between start- and end-date

Tags: regex, date

I am trying to get all logfiles between two dates with regular expressions.

My current expression is `^logfile-?('20120101')`.

From is "20120101" and end is "20120131"for example.

finding a specific logfile is no problem, i have problems to define the between-days-condition.

Comment: Regular expressions probably are not the tool you want for this, but provide some sample input and desired output so we can help.

Comment: Getting them from the shell? Which one? Or in what language else?

Comment: it is ruby. i found the upto-method which is usable for a date either. but still i am interested in the regex which does the same :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the date part of the regex it should be sufficient to search for `201201\d\d`. This will match every String from "20120100" to "20120199", so it would match every day in January.

So probably something like this would do it: [`^logfile-(201201\d\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/Ptao1O/2)

If you want to reduce it to a specific period in the same month (for example from 7th july till 21th july) then it could look like this:

```
201207(0[7-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-1])
```

Comment: This will only work for accurate date boundaries, not for `from is "20120405" and end is "20120503" for example`.

Comment: i understand, but i would like to reduce the days, so i can say: get all logfiles from 7th july till 21th july. 'start' and 'end' are in the same month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import datetime
PSD = datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1)
PED = datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 31)
dateDelta = (PED-PSD).days
STR = '{'
for date in range(dateDelta+1):
  focusedDate = PSD + datetime.timedelta(date)
  STR += focusedDate.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") + ','
STR = STR[:-1] + "}"
print(STR)
```

and the result will look like this:

```
{2019/07/01,2019/07/02,2019/07/03,2019/07/04,2019/07/05,2019/07/06,2019/07/07,2019/07/08,2019/07/09,2019/07/10,2019/07/11,2019/07/12,2019/07/13,2019/07/14,2019/07/15,2019/07/16,2019/07/17,2019/07/18,2019/07/19,2019/07/20,2019/07/21,2019/07/22,2019/07/23,2019/07/24,2019/07/25,2019/07/26,2019/07/27,2019/07/28,2019/07/29,2019/07/30,2019/07/31}
```